# Where md5 column Laravel 5.4

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5.4

Please i try to get row where the md5 of column equal to MD5 value:

This is my code

```
public function xxxx($id_md5){
    $x = Model::where(DB::raw("MD5('id')"),$id_md5)->first();
}
```

Always object is null, Any help please,
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't passing a valid md5 value then.  There's nothing syntactically wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `DB::raw("MD5('id')")`, your database doesn't check the md5 value of the id column - instead, it checks the md5 value of the string `id`. Remove the quote and it'll work.

Tinker example from a db I had open:

```
>>> App\User::where(DB::raw('md5("id")'), md5('1'))->first();
=> null
>>> App\User::where(DB::raw('md5(id)'), md5('1'))->first();
=> App\User {#867
     id: 1,
     username: "testuser1",
   }
```